# gap in employer provided hsa

Tags: hsa

I had a qualified HDHP and HSA Jan to thru April.
Now another qualified HDHP and HSA July thru December
Can I use funds in the second HSA to pay qualified Expenses dated during the first
qualified period.  The first HSA is no longer funded.

Comment: When you got the new HSA did you do a rollover of funds from your prior HSA?

Answer (score 2):

The date on which you open your HSA account is essentially the first day on which expenses can be qualified. So, if your new HSA was opened on July 1, you can only use it for expenses incurred on or after that date - if you had expenses prior to that, you cannot use the new account.

The terms for this are described in the instructions for IRS form [8889](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i8889.pdf).

Comment: Can I go back and individually put funds in the old HSA too pay those expenses under that plan that did not get paid due to depleted funds

Comment: No, you can not. Also that doesn't help you. The advantage is that the HSA is pretax income. Putting money in now (presumably post tax) is the same as just paying the bill.